# Unity barracuda, tensor to implement an onnx model

Tags: unity-game-engine, machine-learning, unityscript, onnx, barracuda

```
Tensor inputTensor = new Tensor(1, 30 * 258, 30*258, 1, keypointsSequence.ToArray());
```

I need to make that barracuda tensor work for an onnx model that receives as input the dimensions (1, 30, 258), I don't know why it doesn't give me and it generates an error.

I am also using barracuda, In addition to this it tells me that the entry is wrong and gives me these problems:

```
AssertionException: Assertion failure. Values are not equal.
Expected: 258 == 7740
UnityEngine.Assertions.Assert.Fail (System.String message, System.String userMessage) (at <30adf90198bc4c4b83910c6fb1877998>:0)
UnityEngine.Assertions.Assert.AreEqual[T] (T expected, T actual, System.String message, System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer`1[T] comparer) (at <30adf90198bc4c4b83910c6fb1877998>:0)
UnityEngine.Assertions.Assert.AreEqual[T] (T expected, T actual, System.String message) (at <30adf90198bc4c4b83910c6fb1877998>:0)
UnityEngine.Assertions.Assert.AreEqual (System.Int32 expected, System.Int32 actual) (at <30adf90198bc4c4b83910c6fb1877998>:0)
Unity.Barracuda.ComputeOps.Dense (Unity.Barracuda.Tensor X, Unity.Barracuda.Tensor W, Unity.Barracuda.Tensor B, Unity.Barracuda.Layer+FusedActivation fusedActivation) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.barracuda@3.0.0/Barracuda/Runtime/Core/Backends/BarracudaCompute.cs:1177)
Unity.Barracuda.PrecompiledComputeOps.Dense (Unity.Barracuda.Tensor X, Unity.Barracuda.Tensor W, Unity.Barracuda.Tensor B, Unity.Barracuda.Layer+FusedActivation fusedActivation) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.barracuda@3.0.0/Barracuda/Runtime/Core/Backends/BarracudaPrecompiledCompute.cs:931)
Unity.Barracuda.ComputeOps.MatMul (Unity.Barracuda.Tensor X, System.Boolean xTranspose, Unity.Barracuda.Tensor Y, System.Boolean yTranspose) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.barracuda@3.0.0/Barracuda/Runtime/Core/Backends/BarracudaCompute.cs:1125)
Unity.Barracuda.ReferenceCPUOps.LSTM (Unity.Barracuda.Tensor X, Unity.Barracuda.Tensor[] W, Unity.Barracuda.Tensor[] R, Unity.Barracuda.Tensor[] Wb, Unity.Barracuda.Tensor[] Rb, Unity.Barracuda.Tensor hidden, Unity.Barracuda.Tensor cell) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.barracuda@3.0.0/Barracuda/Runtime/Core/Backends/BarracudaReferenceCPU.cs:3713)
Unity.Barracuda.StatsOps.LSTM (Unity.Barracuda.Tensor X, Unity.Barracuda.Tensor[] W, Unity.Barracuda.Tensor[] R, Unity.Barracuda.Tensor[] Wb, Unity.Barracuda.Tensor[] Rb, Unity.Barracuda.Tensor hidden, Unity.Barracuda.Tensor cell) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.barracuda@3.0.0/Barracuda/Runtime/Core/Backends/StatsOps.cs:1047)
Unity.Barracuda.GenericWorker+<StartManualSchedule>d__36.MoveNext () (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.barracuda@3.0.0/Barracuda/Runtime/Core/Backends/GenericWorker.cs:1018)
Unity.Barracuda.GenericWorker.Execute () (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.barracuda@3.0.0/Barracuda/Runtime/Core/Backends/GenericWorker.cs:187)
Unity.Barracuda.GenericWorker.Execute (Unity.Barracuda.Tensor input) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.barracuda@3.0.0/Barracuda/Runtime/Core/Backends/GenericWorker.cs:179)
script.DoInference (Unity.Barracuda.Tensor inputTensor) (at Assets/Scripts/script.cs:190)
script+<UpdateKeypointsPer30Frames>d__9.MoveNext () (at Assets/Scripts/script.cs:172)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr returnValueAddress) (at <30adf90198bc4c4b83910c6fb1877998>:0)
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine(IEnumerator)
Visuallizer:LateUpdate() (at Assets/Scripts/Visuallizer.cs:54)
```